# What is a development stack?

Tags: terminology

I am just now in the process of looking for jobs as I am about to graduate from college. An interviewer asked me what my current 'development stack' is?

I know this is probably a really basic question. but could someone explain to me what a 'development stack' is? It isn't a term that gets used in school.

Comment: Just curious, what was your response to the question? The interviewer didn't offer any feedback?

Comment: @JeffO It was actually a questionnaire that got emailed to me, luckily I didn't have to ask them. If it were a real interview, I would have asked for clarification.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It simply means the set of languages, libraries, IDEs and tools (including OS, database server and application server) used for application development.

For example, people may refer to the LAMP stack, meaning Linux/Unix + Apache + MySQL + PHP/Perl.

Other stacks are the Microsoft Stack (Windows + IIS + SQL Server + C#/VB.NET).

Comment: Thank you!, I wasn't really sure what they were asking as when I usually hear the work `stack` I think of other things.

Comment: Similarly, I remember vividly than when I started working I had no idea what a `toolchain` was.

Comment: @XavierT. It's what you wish you could use (I'll leave the details to your imagination) on people who write buggy compilers and development tools. ;)